# Magento 2 add custom button next to cart button

Tags: magento2, module, cart, extensions

I want to add a button next to the cart showed in the screenshot.

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

(EDIT) Only need to know what to write in the layout.xml

This is the current XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <referenceContainer name="minicart.addons">
            <block class="MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Block\Button" name="minicart.movetoquote" template="MassiveArt_ShoppingCart::button_getcart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

and this is how it gets displayed at the moment:

[image]

Comment: The answer I currently got, didn't work for me, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Write in layout app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <referenceBlock name='minicart'>
            <action method='setTemplate'>
                <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_Module::cart/minicart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </page>
```

Next, create template in, app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml file in which your **button code** to be added

```
<?php    
/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('My Cart') ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <button>Return</button>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <script>
            require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
                    $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                });
            });
        </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    **Your button here**
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use my existing .phtml file, where I just add a button and only change the default.xml file this code does not work

Comment: This is one of the preferred way to override phtml file and add custom content to it, in your case button.

Comment: Please look at my updated answer

Comment: sorry ment question

Comment: Can you please check my updated answer, I tried in my Magento and it is working.

Comment: as before it just won't work