# Magento 2.4.1 If shopping cart is not empty place a Go To Shopping Cart button next to Add To Cart on Product Detail page

Tags: magento2, cart, product-view, magento2.4.1, product-detail-page

When the shopping cart is NOT empty, I want a button next to the Add To Cart button on the product detail page and have it go to the Shopping Cart

File using to override is:
/app/design/frontend/THEME/default/Magento_Catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Below is my current code without the check shopping cart for items code. I want to only show the Go To Cart button if something is in the cart.

```
<div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                class="action primary tocart"
                id="product-addtocart-button"
                 style="width:50%;" disabled>
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" onclick="location.href='/checkout/cart/'" class="action secondary tocart"
                id="product-addtocart-button"
                 style="width:49%; margin-right:0;">
            <span>Go To Cart</span>
        </button>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    </div>
```

I've tried the various solutions out there including [Magento 2 add custom button next to cart button](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286046/magento-2-add-custom-button-next-to-cart-button) and even checking it using the cart helper like https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-data-shopping-cart-items-subtotal-grand-total-billing-shipping-address-magento-2.html and

```
$helper = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
$helper->getItemsCount(); ?>
```

Definitely not working.

Comment: Did you try `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart`?

Comment: Yes that is in the last link mageplaza.com that I referenced. Which is why I believe something changed from 2.3.5 to 2.4.1 where this no longer works. mageplaza lays it all out there and it did not work for me.